# Clean client side libraries is not working in asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core

When I right click on **libman.json** file in `asp.net core 3.0` project, and select clean client side libraries, it does not clear the created folder .

Comment: It seems to be a feature of `libman`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#delete-library-files  You'd better open an issue as a suggestion under it. https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager

Comment: Do you mean that the generated folder under **wwwroot** have not been deleted after clicking **clean client-side libraries**? I tested it in ASP.NET Core3.0 &2.2, but it will be deleted by selecting clean client side libraries.